# Struts 1 manipulate value of index

Tags: loops, struts, jsp-tags

I'm using struts1.
I have a list (searchList) to be displayed in jsp
this list has 30 rows

And I want to display it in 3 tables.
mainly speaking first 10 items on first table, and so on

When using `<logic:iterate>` I want to access the value of index, and just add + 10 on the next table, and another 10 on the next one.
I don't know how to do this

my code is something like

```
<logic:iterate id="list" name="formName" property="searchList" indexId="i">
<bean:write name="formName" property='<%="list["+ (i.intValue() + 10) + "]"%>' />
</logic:iterate>
```

but what this does is just concatenate the index and "10".
Please helpppp.

Comment: Personally, I'd break the list up on the Java side, and keep the view layer simple.

Comment: I have thought of this way too, but I'm just hoping somebody could find a way for this.

Comment: It doesn't. Post generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `offset` and `length` attribute in your `<logic:iterate>` tag. For example,

2nd table:

```
<logic:iterate id="list" name="formName" property="searchList" indexId="i" offset="10" length="10">
```

3rd table:

```
<logic:iterate id="list" name="formName" property="searchList" indexId="i" offset="20" length="10">
```